# What is an efficient setup for designing and testing O365 web parts?

Tags: development, apps-development, testing

I have just been immersed into the deep end of sharepoint development; and then some: developing web parts for O365 sharepoint. Right now I am using a 'deploy and see' development model, but I would really like to establish a more efficient way for designing and testing my web parts in Visual Studio before deploying them.

I'm sure other developers have handled this very paint point and would like some suggestions on to set up, maybe, a local MVC/WebForms project, where I can quickly make design and code changes locally before deploying them to my test site.